# Syncfusion Charts for flutter, stacked bar chart render the bars is weird behavior

Tags: flutter, syncfusion-chart

I am using Syncfusion charts for flutter and trying to render a Stacked chart bar
but as you can see in the images below it renders the bars in a weird way and leaves a gap between them
where it should start from zero or it should be linked with prev bar in case of stacked

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the interest in our Flutter charts. We have analyzed your query and unable to replicate the reported issue at our end. Please share the replication sample will help us to analyze your situation and provide the solution to you sooner. You can also contact us through our [support forums](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums), [Direct-Trac](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents), or [feedback](https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback) portal if you need any further assistance. We are always happy to assist you!